# .htaccess Rewriterule not wot working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wp-rewrite

Why below code piece does not work?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^custom$ index.php?pagename=mypage [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

When I navigate to `mydomain.com/custom` it gives a 404 page. If I write it directly inside my wordpress as below, it works, but why it doesn't work inside .htaccess?

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_alexes_rules' );
function add_alexes_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^custom$', 'index.php?pagename=mypage', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Comment: maybe `mod_headers` module isn't included

Comment: @Deadooshka I removed mod_headers and it did not affect.

Comment: If you request `/index.php?pagename=mypage` directly, does it "work"?

Comment: @user82217 If I wrote it to my browser, it works.

Comment: Whereabouts are you putting these directives? They would need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, _before_ the WordPress front controller.

Comment: @user82217 , I have updated my question and used my complete .htaccess file. You can see it is near the top.

Comment: WP uses php-server-variables to handle request thru the index.php, so rule must change that variable.

Comment: It is not just WP, internal rewrites don't work with many other PHP frameworks that use a front controller rule and depend on `$_SERVER` variables to route the requests.

Answer (score -1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The question asked why their .htaccess code wasn't working.  Even if you provided working code it would be a lot better answer if you describe why your code is better/what the problem is.